# Specify input and output files in Snakefile

Tags: snakemake

I'm new to Snakemake and I want to make a pipeline that takes a given input text file and concatenates its content to a given output file. However I want to be able to specify the names of both the input and output files at run time, so neither file names are hardcoded in the Snakefile. Right now all I can come up with is:

```
rule all:
        input:
                "{input}.txt",
                "{output}.txt"

rule output_files:
        input:
                "{input}.txt"
        output:
                "{output}.txt"
        shell:
                "cat {input}.txt > {output}.txt"
```

I tried running this with "snakemake input1.txt output.txt" but I got the error:

> Building DAG of jobs...
> WildcardError in line 6 of Snakefile:
> Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
> 'input'

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you actually *copy* a single input file into an output file using a `cat` shell command. That could be understood as an intention to concatenate several inputs into one output:

```
rule concatenate:
    input:
        "input1.txt",
        "input2.txt"
    output:
        "output.txt"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

> takes a given input text file and concatenates its content to a given output file

Another way to understand the question is that you are trying to append an input file to the end of the output. That is more challenging: Snakemake "thinks" in terms of goals where each goal is a distinct file. How would Snakemake know if the output file is a raw one or if it is a concatenated version? One way to do that is to have "flag" files: the presence of such file would mean that the goal is achieved and no concatenation is needed. One more problem: Snakemake clears the output file before running the rule. Than means that you need to specify it as a input:

```
rule append:
    input:
        in = "input.txt",
        out = "output.txt"
    output:
        flag = "flag"
    shell:
        "cat {input.in} >> {input.out} && touch {output.flag}"
```

Now back to your question regarding the error and the way to specify the filenames in runtime. You get this error because the wildcards should be fully inferred from the `output` section, and both your rules are ill-formed. Let's start with the `rule all`.

You need to say Snakemake what goal you are building. No wildcards in the `input`, everything should be disambigued:

```
def getInput():
    pass
    # form the actual goal (you may query the database, service, hardcode, etc.)

rule all:
    input: getInput
```

Let's say you decided that the goal should be 3 files: `["output1.txt", "output3.txt", "output3.txt"]`:

```
def getInput():
    magic_numbers_from_oracle = ["1", "2", "3"]
    return magic_numbers_from_oracle

rule all:
    input: expand("output{number}.txt", number=getInput())
```

Ok, now Snakemake knows the goal. The next step is to write a rule that says how to create a single `output{number}.txt` file. For simplicity I'm taking your initial approach with cat/copying:

```
rule cat_copy:
    input:
        "input{n}.txt"
    output:
        "output{n}.txt"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

That's it. As long as you have files *input1.txt*, *input2.txt*, *input3.txt* you would get the corresponding outputs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dmitry, however in your example you assumed the input files have the formats input1, input2, and input3.txt. For my application I don't want to assume anything about the file names of input and output files besides knowing that they are both .txt files. I want to generalize it so that I can choose to cat a.txt > b.txt this time, and maybe cat yy.txt > zz.txt next time. That's why I was asking if there's a way to specify the input and output file names when snakemake is run.

Comment: @user9367574, so far your task is poorly defined. How would the script understand what's in your mind? What's common in `a.txt > b.txt` and `yy.txt > zz.txt`? How would Snakemake decide that you want `a.txt > b.txt` but not `a.txt > c.txt`? I gave you an idea to setup the task in a database, but that is up to you how to provide this info.

Comment: I was wondering whether you can tell snakemake the input and output file names at run time. In the command that I tried to use earlier ("snakemake input1.txt output.txt"), I was trying to tell Snakemake that the input file is called input1.txt and output file was called output.txt, and it should do input1.txt > output.txt. Obviously this didn't work, but I was wondering if there's a way to do this.

Comment: @user9367574 you can do that, but that would be mostly Python without Snakemake. The purpose of Snakemake is to run pipelines that have some known patterns. If you don't know your patterns, you don't need Snakemake: just run the shell command from Python.